# BadMethodCallException when using withDefault() method

Tags: php, laravel

For some reason, I am getting a BadMethodCallException when using the `withDefault()` method. That's what I have in my Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->withDefault([
        'name' => 'Guest Author',
    ]);
}
```

I got:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2451: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withDefault() in Builder.php
>   line 2451

Answer (score 2):

After an hour of searching, I found that it was because I was currently using an older laravel version which did not have the `withDefault` method available. I have upgraded it from 5.4.23 to 5.4.32 (latest) by simply running `composer update.`

You can check your current laravel version by running `php artisan --version`

For the more curious, the `withDefault` method was introduced in Laravel version 5.4.28 through these PRs: [#19733](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19733/files), [#19788](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19788), [1137d86](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/1137d860d8ef009630ae4951ea6323f552571268)

Comment: i tried it didn't work is there anything that i can do